# how can I make the darkness of this elevation more or less? Android

Tags: android, react-native

I  am a very beginner with React Native and trying to get a dark shadow for my Android app. I noticed that

```
shadowColor: '#1C0222',
shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 20 },
shadowOpacity: 0.1
```

won't work for Andriod but instead, i can use `elevation` how can I make the darkness of this elevation more or less? something like opacity.

Comment: by augmenting the elevation number ?

Comment: when i increase the number it just make it taller, not darker

Comment: change shadow color (darker) with elevation

Comment: shadowColor works for ios only, any way to do it for Android too?

Answer (score 0):

While using elevation there is no control over the blur radius, opacity, and offset of the box shadow; we only have control over the color of the shadow. So if there is no limitation regarding using an external library, you can also use the library "react-native-shadow-2". It will allow more control over the shadows.

Installation:

-First npm install react-native-svg.
If on expo, npx expo install react-native-svg@13.4.0 (The current supported version).

-Then install react-native-shadow-2: npm i react-native-shadow-2

Structure:

```
import { Shadow } from 'react-native-shadow-2';

<Shadow distance={15} >
   <View>
      {/* Your code*/}
   </View>
</Shadow>
```

The distance property will allow you to increase or decrease the intensity of the shadow. However you'll need to play with the styles a little to get the desired result. There are many props such as startColor, finalColor, radius, offset. You can use as per your requirements. Kindly refer to the [docs](https://github.com/SrBrahma/react-native-shadow-2)